# Error response from daemon: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space (when on VPN)

Tags: vpn, docker, subnet

In Ubuntu I am trying to create a docker network with a specified subnet when on VPN but I get the below error:

```
$ docker network create my-network --subnet 172.17.24.0/18
Error response from daemon: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space
```

Looking at the route table:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 cscotun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0        0 wlp0s20f3
10.174.33.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cscotun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 cscotun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp0s20f3
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
188.64.152.45   192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlp0s20f3
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cscotun0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 wlp0s20f3
```

I don't see that my VPN (`cscotun0`) is occupying that range so what is going on?

Unless `172.17.24.0/18` is overlapping with `docker0`:

```
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

but I assume both `docker0` and `172.17.24.0/18` should be able to exist in the same range?

Answer (score 0):

Error response from daemon: The network pool overlaps with another one on this address space.

In my case, I had a docker-compose.yaml file with a hardcoded network IP address, and another container was started with the same network.

```
networks:
    vpn-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.21.0.2
```

To solve this, first, find the current container that is using it:

```
# docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME                DRIVER    SCOPE
ca9b2b29a253   bridge              bridge    local
45e9488d9140   host                host      local
5966656f9981   none                null      local
b3edda2ed475   my-service-net      bridge    local
a9eb7c1f3d20   another-network     bridge    local

# docker inspect my-service-net | grep 172.21.0.2
    "IPv4Address": "172.21.0.2/16"
```

Stop the service for the found network:

```
# docker stop my-service-net
```

Finally, start the new container that is failing. You can also remove the IP network configuration or change the IP.

Answer (score 0):

> but I assume both docker0 and 172.17.24.0/18 should be able to exist in the same range?

In theory this is *allowable*, but it would result in a hole in the 172.17.0.0/16 network, where 172.17.24.0/18 via `docker0` due to the most specific route winning. The Linux kernel will probably let you configure this, but it's not good form, and it *will* lead to interesting problems, due to the overlapping network subnets.

The solution is to make address space non-overlapping.